# sending the date in the subject in crontab

Tags: mysql, crontab, mysqldump

In crontab I have the following cronjob working.

0 0 * * * mysqldump -e --user=root  --password=MYPASSWORD MYDB | gzip | uuencode db_`date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d"`.gz | mail -s '`date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d"`_dump' john@example.com

I expect the email I get to have the subject 2013-09-14_dump 
and the attachment to be called db_2013-09-14_dump.gz

however when I revieve this email the attachment is as expected by the subject in my inbox is `date +"%Y-%m-%d"`_dump

What am i doing wrong here?
How can I get the subject to be the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls to `date` need to be in backquotes:

```
mysqldump -e --user=root --password=MYPASSWORD MYDB | gzip | uuencode db_`date "%Y-\%m-%d"`.gz | mail -s `date +"%Y-\%m-%d"`_dump john@example.com
```

Backquotes tells the shell to run the backquoted comment and to insert its output into the command line.